# Return promise of one of the union type

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-typescript

I have got this code base whereby I am getting TS error. Can someone please help?

```js
export type InitResult = {canInit: boolean; reason: string}
export type ResolveParams = InitResult | boolean

export function selectMethod(
  payload: {resolve?: (value: ResolveParams) => void} = {},
): void {
  //
  return undefined
}

const component_one_setup = (): Promise<boolean> =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    // ts error:  Type '(value: boolean | PromiseLike<boolean>) => void' is not assignable to type '(value: ResolveParams) => void'.
    selectMethod({resolve})
  })

const component_two_setup = (): Promise<InitResult> =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    // ts error:  Type '(value: InitResult | PromiseLike<InitResult>) => void' is not assignable to type '(value: ResolveParams) => void'
    selectMethod({resolve})
  })
```

`component_one_setup` returns `Promise<boolean>` and `component_two_setup` returns `Promise<InitResult>`. Both are calling a method that would accept **resolve** of boolean or `InitResult`.
But Typescript is throwing error:

```js
Type '(value: boolean | PromiseLike<boolean>) => void' is not assignable to type '(value: ResolveParams) => void'
```

Comment: Really your `selectMethod` should construct and return the promise

Comment: How does `selectMethod` decide whether it passes an `InitResult` or a `boolean` into the resolve function? If this cannot somehow be chosen as part of the call, TypeScript is legitimately pointing out a bug in your code here.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the `selectMethod` function to a TS generic function.

```
export type InitResult = { canInit: boolean; reason: string };


export function selectMethod<Resolve extends (value: any) => void>(payload: { resolve?: Resolve }): void {

  payload.resolve?.(true)
  // or
  payload.resolve?.({ canInit: false, reason: 'a' })

  return undefined
}

const component_one_setup = (): Promise<boolean> => new Promise((resolve) => {
  selectMethod({ resolve })
});

const component_two_setup = (): Promise<InitResult> => new Promise((resolve) => {
  selectMethod({ resolve })
});
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCSA7AljASsAZwFcAbeAXjgG84BjAQw0xwC44AjCCE4RgbjhReBCBjYEYULBgDmcAL58AUCtCRYcAGZEMtGFlFwCwHnoCywGAAsIAEwA8+ESQBuqUDGAZbBOAAoXehIiYDZGRABKOHIAPjgXCCxbGL8wekQSCHpbNhohZzcAfjYnbjcFCLYEpOoVODg0jKzbADp8suBClr9JEIileoB6QbhoAYb0zOy2wg6uvxoGJmwYNk0g4wAaQWFRNgByen2Kup2YIigMOB1bYE1pYFsleRVaUQk6CABbSAwvGAA+qJgADjOcwNF-JU4AAFKDfLDGeycbi8DBxWJwP4Ad1h8K+iOAfj87VcwCimKo42MphgFmsdgWOwKqHk-TZyiUbwwHzeP2BGEBMGxEFBliIEMofmhcIRSOYeEIpBgGLiOLxcqJJNmZIpcSp9RpwHMlhstiZpPKbOeET4QA)

Comment: Thanks @Lin, that helps. But now I am being blocked by app lint rules `If you are expecting the function to accept certain arguments, you should explicitly define the function shape  @typescript-eslint/ban-types` .

Comment: The generic seems like a good idea, but notice the actual solution here is the use of `any`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve above issue by modifying the code as below:

```
export type InitResult =  {canInit:boolean; reason:string};
export type ResolveParams = InitResult | boolean;
export type ResolveFunction = (value:InitResult | boolean)=>void;

export function selectMethod(payload: { resolve?: ResolveFunction} = {}): void {
 //
 return undefined
}

const component_one_setup = (): Promise<boolean> => new Promise((resolve) => {
 selectMethod({ resolve: resolve as ResolveFunction })
});

const component_two_setup = (): Promise<InitResult> => new Promise((resolve) => {
  selectMethod({ resolve: resolve as ResolveFunction })
});
```

[working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCSA7AljASsAZwFcAbeAXjjgG8BjAQw0xwC4AjCCE4Rgbjig8CEDCwIwoWDAHMAvrwBQoSLATJU%20YSQBuwAAr0o9ALYE4lZnkKl4AHzgcuPDIuXR4SFHE1ddAMSIMWhgsEXM4AAptehIiYBZLTRs4e0duRgBKcgA%20bQgsABNFJXB3OAAzQODQjDgCYG5ggFlgGAALCAKIsHpEEgh6ApYaAUJfYAB%20YZ8dYACgkJFZcOpZDOG8wpoFOAB6XZ3BGCIoWsCC4HKpYAKFWQUFWhFxOCfjSAxgDBgAfRFgH71Y5gcIRdZwPRQCDGLD1AA8aWc2XMyM%20AHcIVCYfUIhFBFpdBkUds6g1gM1Wh0utRRgT4rTxnB6GYZv4qotams7hlik8MC83h8vr8YGiIIDWkQQZQwcNIdDYcA4YlrGRkTk4OjMQqcXixrMiRrqDtSY0YC12p0IjT8eNhrbZkyWfq2QsanAuWteEA)